# List view cell recycling issue

Tags: android, listview, recycle

In my case list view on scroll showing duplicate cells. Not working properly. this is my code in getView()

```
    if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_cell, null);
        }

        try {
            if(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getPhone() != null) {
                ImageView contactIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
                TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                contactName.setText(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getDisplayName());
                contactIcon.setImageBitmap(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getThumbNail());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to yuor `getView()` method

```
if(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getPhone() != null) {
    ImageView contactIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    contactName.setText(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getDisplayName());
    contactIcon.setImageBitmap(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getThumbNail());
}else{
    ImageView contactIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    contactName.setText("");
    contactIcon.setImageBitmap(null);
}
```

It happens when `getPhone()` returns null and `convertView` does not update.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your problem:

```
if(contacts.getContacts().get(position).getPhone() != null)
```

What are you doing if the phone is null?
You are leaving the old content inside the view. You should provide some placeholders for this condition.
Same thing for the exception. And btw why are you catching an exception there?